# Is it a good idea to use bloom filters for this scenario?

Tags: data-structures

I have a theoretical social network where two people, A & C, can become friends if and only if, they have a common friend B amongst them.

The simplest solution is to iterate over the two lists and see if they have any friends in common. My question is, can I use bloom filters instead? I will have a bloom filter for every user with their friend list added. When I need to check if a common friend exists I check A's friend list with C's bloom filter first and if I get a positive result I actually perform iteration to confirm.

Given that the average friend list size if 100 friends, will this implementation be better than simple iteration?

Comment: Iterating over the two lists is O(n).  My understanding of the bloom filter is that it is probabilistic and it is possible that you will allow friending when there is no common friend. Is this acceptable?

Comment: What is your storage mechanism?  If it's a SQL database, there already is a mechanism that can be used for this purpose (a self-join to the `people` table).

Comment: @MichaelT this is not possible but I was going to iterate over the list of friends if and only if the bloom filter returned a (false?) positive.

Comment: @RobertHarvey we cache a majority of the data in redis so no SQL.

Comment: @MichaelT: In short, a bloom filter can tell whether a particular key is **not** in a given dataset. What it can't tell is, whether the key is *for sure* in there. So you get clear NOs but maybe YESses.

Answer (score 2):

No, bloom filters are not suited for your case.

Bloom filters use case is following:

- you have *very* large datasets that typically don't fit in memory
- you want to check if it contains given elements, false positives being possible

In other words, it's a trick to fit something in memory that is actually bigger, but on the downside we accept false positives. This is both overkill and ill-suited for your case where you want to compare two lists of friends.

What you should do:

Just put one list in a hash set for O(1) "contain" operations, and iterate with the other list.

EDIT:

A reviewer changed this with *does not contain*, this is neither wrong nor true, it's just the other face of the medal. To make it more clear:

- if the bloom filter gives a hit: the item is *probably* inside
- if the bloom filter gives a miss: the item is certainly not inside

...in other words:

- if an item is inside: you always get a hit
- if an item is not inside: you *probably* get a miss

...yeah, that's the thing about probabilistic data structures. You can also see it that way: there are more keys hitting than items inside.